# How does a EC2 machine prevent ssh root access with a warning?

Tags: shell, ssh, root, amazon-ec2, aws

I've setup a machine on EC2 running Debian stretch.
Upon trying to ssh as root, I get the following message:

```
$ ssh -i "mykey" root@machine
Please login as the user "admin" rather than the user "root".

^C
Connection to machine closed.
```

Note the `^C` - the command doesn't terminate.

I can login as `admin` without a problem, and I'm aware of *why* this is done - I'm not sure about *how*, though.

My first hunch was the shell

```
admin@machine:~$ grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Nope. I checked nologin just in case:

```
admin@machine:~$ /usr/sbin/nologin  This account is currently not available.
```

Different message.

What is the mechanism that makes the system print out the message on login?

Answer (score 6):

```
admin@machine:~$ sudo su 

root@machine:# cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys 

no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo
'Please login as the user \"admin\" rather than the user
\"root\".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa ...
```

So that explains it. This is done through a custom command in the authorized_keys format - see the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section on [the sshd manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) for details.

As has been pointed out in comments, the reason for the `sleep` is likely so that PuTTY users have time to read the message

Comment: Why not using `PermitRootLogin no` in `sshd_config`?

Comment: My guess is: that should terminate, and a windowed client is likely to close the window. Without the sleep, your average PuTTY user would only notice that "it doesn't work".

Comment: You may want to clarify the subject of your question... "How does an EC2 remote ssh server send a login warning message?" ... and then you could greatly improve your answer by providing an appropriate reference to the `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` section of the [manpage for ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) ... otherwise, it's very unclear what is being asked and answered...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I didn't create the AMI image, so I can't know for sure, but my guess is that having the user message there helps people, compared to a generic "Permission denied" error

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Good point, I didn't think of PuTTY, that's probably the reason

Comment: @goncalopp I do not sacrifice the security rules and  Unix directives of the lesser services open/active for the sake of "helping" users. root is root, is not to be used. Hence my comment.

Comment: @RubberStamp Good points, thank you for the feedback, I've changed the title to be more specific, clarified the question being asked and linked to the manual - thanks for the link!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I agree with you that `PermitRootLogin` is simpler, and has less moving parts. Can you elaborate on how this setup is less secure? What's the concrete attack that you have in mind?

Comment: Basic opsec. Making a mistake, bad .ssh permissions or home not mounted, could mean the game is over.

Answer (score -1):

Below mentioned configuration will refuse root user to be logged in

vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

PermitRootLogin no

AllowUsers [username]